# prove diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\Lambda$ is a real diagonal $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct diagonal entries. Show that $\Lambda B=B\Lambda$ for some $n\times n$ matrix if and only if $B$ is also a diagonal matrix.

Comment: It's also true if B is similar to a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Mike I didn't know the eigenvalues had to be distinct, thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: @ZettaSuro: Actually I misread your comment... I have deleted mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider $B\lambda=[\lambda_1 b_1,\ldots,\lambda_n b_n]$. Then it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Just compare the off-diagonal entries of $\Lambda B$ and $B\Lambda$.

Answer (score 3):

If $B$ is diagonal, it is easy to see it commutes with $\Lambda$.

If $\Lambda$ is real, diagonal and has distinct eigenvalues, then the corresponding eigenvectors are (up to a multiple) $e_1,...,e_n$. That is, $\Lambda e_k = \lambda_k e_k$, where $\lambda_k = [\Lambda]_{kk}$.

If $\Lambda B = B \Lambda$, then see that each column of $B$, say $b_k$, satisfies $\Lambda b_k = \lambda_k b_k$, hence we must have the form $b_k = \beta_k e_k$, from some $\beta_k$. It follows that $B$ has the form $B=\operatorname{diag}(\beta_1,...,\beta_n)$.

Comment: According your answer, "If $\Lambda B=B\Lambda$, then see that each column of $B$, say $b_{k}$, satisfies $\Lambda b_{k}=\lambda_{k}b_{k}$",I am not sure that $\Lambda b_{k}=\lambda_{k}b_{k}$ holds,since $B$ is not symmetric.

Comment: There is no apriori requirement that $B$ be symmetric. If $\Lambda B = B \Lambda$, then $\Lambda B = \Lambda \begin{bmatrix} b_1 & \cdots & b_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda b_1 & \cdots & \Lambda b_n \end{bmatrix} = B \Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 b_1 & \cdots & \lambda_n b_n \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I think you strategy is $B\Lambda=[\lambda_{1}b_{1}\cdots\lambda_{n}b_{n}]$. After I calculated $B\Lambda$, I think you are right.